# How can I change a heatmap from D3 in bicolor heatmap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, heatmap

The code reads data from a file and generate this heatmap:

[image]

But I want the cells in the top diagonal in different color like gradient blue and the cells in the bottom diagonal like now, How can I do it?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Heat map</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='tooltip' class='hidden'>
 <p><span id='value'></p>
</div>
<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
</select>
<div id='chart' style='overflow:auto; width:960px; height:700px;'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var margin = { top: 75, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 100 },
cellSize=12;
col_number=34;
row_number=34;
width = cellSize*col_number, // - margin.left - margin.right,
height = cellSize*row_number , // - margin.top - margin.bottom,
gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
legendElementWidth = cellSize*2.5,
colorBuckets = 11,
colors = ['#FFFFFF','#F1EEF6','#E6D3E1','#DBB9CD','#D19EB9','#C684A4','#BB6990','#B14F7C','#A63467','#9B1A53','#91003F'];
hcrow = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34], // change to gene name or probe id
hccol = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34], // change to gene name or probe id
rowLabel = ['From 0-14', 'From 15-29', 'From 30-44', 'From 45-59', 'From 60-74', 'From 75-89', 'From 90-104', 'From 105-119', 'From 120-134', 'From 135-149', 'From 150-164', 'From 165-179', 'From 180-194', 'From 195-209', 'From 210-224', 'From 225-239', 'From 240-254', 'From 255-269', 'From 270-284', 'From 285-299', 'From 300-314', 'From 315-329', 'From 330-344', 'From 345-359', 'From 360-374', 'From 375-389', 'From 390-404', 'From 405-419', 'From 420-434', 'From 435-449', 'From 450-464', 'From 465-479', 'From 480-494', 'From 495-509'], // change to gene name or probe id
colLabel = ['To 0-14', 'To 15-29', 'To 30-44', 'To 45-59', 'To 60-74', 'To 75-89', 'To 90-104', 'To 105-119', 'To 120-134', 'To 135-149', 'To 150-164', 'To 165-179', 'To 180-194', 'To 195-209', 'To 210-224', 'To 225-239', 'To 240-254', 'To 255-269', 'To 270-284', 'To 285-299', 'To 300-314', 'To 315-329', 'To 330-344', 'To 345-359', 'To 360-374', 'To 375-389', 'To 390-404', 'To 405-419', 'To 420-434', 'To 435-449', 'To 450-464', 'To 465-479', 'To 480-494', 'To 495-509']; // change to contrast name
d3.tsv("data_heatmap.tsv",

function(d) {
  return {
    row:   +d.row_idx,
    col:   +d.col_idx,
    value: +d.repetitions
  };
},

function(error, data) {
  var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
      .domain([0, 10])
      .range(colors);

  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  ;

  var heatMap = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class","g3")
      .selectAll(".cellg")
      .data(data,function(d){return d.row+":"+d.col;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return hccol.indexOf(d.col) * cellSize; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return hcrow.indexOf(d.row) * cellSize; })
      .attr("class", function(d){return "cell cell-border cr"+(d.row-1)+" cc"+(d.col-1);})
      .attr("width", cellSize)
      .attr("height", cellSize)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); })
  ;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I try to run your code but i don't have colors_dos variable

Comment: @Przemek I Solved it, now I simplifyed the code, any idea to have two colors, one for the top digonal and one for the bottom diagonal?

Comment: Wher I can find data_heatmap.tsv?

Comment: @Przemek you can find it here:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz076m2t0rvib88/data_heatmap.tsv?dl=0

Comment: I solved @Przemek, thnaks for all!

Answer (score 1):

I solved used a trick in `var heatmap` into `.style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); })` and I changed it for `if (d.col < d.row) {return colorScaleBottom(d.value); }else{if(d.col == d.row){return colorScaleDiagonal(d.value);}else{return colorScaleTop(d.value);} } })`

Finally I declarated three new variables with the colors:

```
colors_bottom =    ['#FFFFFF','#F1EEF6','#E6D3E1','#DBB9CD','#D19EB9','#C684A4','#BB6990','#B14F7C','#A63467','#9B1A53','#91003F'];
colors_top = ['#FFFFFF','#ebebfa','#d6d6f5','#c2c2f0','#adadeb','#9999e6','#8585e0','#7070db','#5c5cd6','#4747d1','#3333cc'];
colors_diagonal = ['#FFFFFF','#e6ffee','#b3ffcc','#80ffaa','#4dff88','#00ff55','#00e64d','#00cc44','#00b33c','#00802b','#006622'];
```

Thats the way to obtain this Heatmap:
[image]

Complete code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Heat map</title>
  </head>
<body>

<div id='tooltip' class='hidden'>
 <p><span id='value'></p>
</div>

<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>

<div id='chart' style='overflow:auto; width:960px; height:700px;'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var margin = { top: 75, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 100 },
cellSize=12;
col_number=34;
row_number=34;
width = cellSize*col_number, // - margin.left - margin.right,
height = cellSize*row_number , // - margin.top - margin.bottom,
gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
legendElementWidth = cellSize*2.5,
colorBuckets = 11,
colors_bottom = ['#FFFFFF','#F1EEF6','#E6D3E1','#DBB9CD','#D19EB9','#C684A4','#BB6990','#B14F7C','#A63467','#9B1A53','#91003F'];
colors_top = ['#FFFFFF','#ebebfa','#d6d6f5','#c2c2f0','#adadeb','#9999e6','#8585e0','#7070db','#5c5cd6','#4747d1','#3333cc'];
colors_diagonal = ['#FFFFFF','#e6ffee','#b3ffcc','#80ffaa','#4dff88','#00ff55','#00e64d','#00cc44','#00b33c','#00802b','#006622'];
hcrow = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34], // change to gene name or probe id
hccol = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34], // change to gene name or probe id
rowLabel = ['From 0-14', 'From 15-29', 'From 30-44', 'From 45-59', 'From 60-74', 'From 75-89', 'From 90-104', 'From 105-119', 'From 120-134', 'From 135-149', 'From 150-164', 'From 165-179', 'From 180-194', 'From 195-209', 'From 210-224', 'From 225-239', 'From 240-254', 'From 255-269', 'From 270-284', 'From 285-299', 'From 300-314', 'From 315-329', 'From 330-344', 'From 345-359', 'From 360-374', 'From 375-389', 'From 390-404', 'From 405-419', 'From 420-434', 'From 435-449', 'From 450-464', 'From 465-479', 'From 480-494', 'From 495-509'], // change to gene name or probe id
colLabel = ['To 0-14', 'To 15-29', 'To 30-44', 'To 45-59', 'To 60-74', 'To 75-89', 'To 90-104', 'To 105-119', 'To 120-134', 'To 135-149', 'To 150-164', 'To 165-179', 'To 180-194', 'To 195-209', 'To 210-224', 'To 225-239', 'To 240-254', 'To 255-269', 'To 270-284', 'To 285-299', 'To 300-314', 'To 315-329', 'To 330-344', 'To 345-359', 'To 360-374', 'To 375-389', 'To 390-404', 'To 405-419', 'To 420-434', 'To 435-449', 'To 450-464', 'To 465-479', 'To 480-494', 'To 495-509']; // change to contrast name
d3.tsv("data_heatmap.tsv",

function(d) {
  return {
    row:   +d.row_idx,
    col:   +d.col_idx,
    value: +d.repetitions
  };
},

function(error, data) {
  var colorScaleBottom = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range(colors_bottom);

  var colorScaleTop = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range(colors_top);

  var colorScaleDiagonal = d3.scale.quantile()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range(colors_diagonal);

  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  ;

  var heatMap = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","g3")
    .selectAll(".cellg")
    .data(data,function(d){return d.row+":"+d.col;})
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return hccol.indexOf(d.col) * cellSize; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return hcrow.indexOf(d.row) * cellSize; })
    .attr("class", function(d){return "cell cell-border cr"+(d.row-1)+" cc"+(d.col-1);})
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .style("fill", function(d) { 
         if (d.col < d.row) {return colorScaleBottom(d.value); }
          else    {
           if(d.col == d.row){return colorScaleDiagonal(d.value);}
            else{return colorScaleTop(d.value);} } })
 ;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```