# What are hccol and hcrow in d3.js heatmaps?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I'm pretty new to d3, but was trying to make a heatmap off of [this](http://bl.ocks.org/ianyfchang/8119685) example. However, I just don't understand what `hcrow` and `hccol` signify. I googled it a little bit, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431127/how-can-i-change-a-heatmap-from-d3-in-bicolor-heatmap) shorter example with `hcrow` and `hccol`. What do these mean? How do they affect the heatmap?

`hcrow` and `hccol` in the first example is as follows:

```
hcrow = [49,11,30,4,18,6,12,20,19,33,32,26,44,35,38,3,23,41,22,10,2,15,16,36,8,25,29,7,27,34,48,31,45,43,14,9,39,1,37,47,42,21,40,5,28,46,50,17,24,13], // change to gene name or probe id
hccol = [6,5,41,12,42,21,58,56,14,16,43,15,17,46,47,48,54,49,37,38,25,22,7,8,2,45,9,20,24,44,23,19,13,40,11,1,39,53,10,52,3,26,27,60,50,51,59,18,31,32,30,4,55,28,29,57,36,34,33,35], // change to gene name or probe id
```

and in the second example:

```
hcrow = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34], // change to gene name or probe id
hccol = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34], // change to gene name or probe id
```

I know that the `hcrow.length` is the number of rows, and `hccol.length` the number of columns of the heatmap respectively... but what do the values inside the array mean? To my knowledge, both are a way to create the grid and generate `x,y` points, correct? But what would be the significance of having a non-ordered list?

for example the heatmap squares' position for the first example are created as follows:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return hccol.indexOf(d.col) * cellSize; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return hcrow.indexOf(d.row) * cellSize; })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of asking...

> what are `hccol` and `hcrow` in d3.js heatmaps?

... it's better asking:

> what are `hccol` and `hcrow` in **this particular code**?

The explanation is simple: the author of that code is using these two arrays for positioning the rectangles (and the labels as well) in the heatmap.

Let's see an example. In this demo snippet, I'm creating a data array with 100 objects. Each object has a number (0 to 9) for the row and the column, and a value (that I'm using to set the color) which is just a multiplication of those two numbers.

Then, when positioning the rectangles, I'm using:

```
.attr("x", d => hccol.indexOf(d.col)*40)
.attr("y", d => hcrow.indexOf(d.row)*40)
```

With these variables:

```
var hccol = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var hcrow = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

So, for instance, if `d.col` is 3, the respective rectangle will be positioned at the fourth column (index of 3 in the `hccol` array, which is the fourth value).

Check it:

```js
var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
  data.push({col: i, row: j, value: i*j})
 }
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 400);
 
var hccol = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var hcrow = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, 81])
 .range(["white", "red"]);
 
var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("width", 40)
 .attr("height", 40)
 .attr("stroke", "gray")
 .attr("x", d=>hccol.indexOf(d.col)*40)
 .attr("y", d=>hcrow.indexOf(d.row)*40)
 .attr("fill", d=>color(d.value));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

You can see that the cells are positioned according to their values. As both `hccol` and `hcrow` grow from 0 to 9, you have a nice, symmetrical heatmap.

Now, in this second snippet, let's mess with `hccol` and `hcrow`:

```
var hccol = [4, 1, 9, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 0, 7];
var hcrow = [0, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 9, 6];
```

Look the result:

```js
var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
  data.push({col: i, row: j, value: i*j})
 }
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 400);
 
var hccol = [4, 1, 9, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 0, 7];
var hcrow = [0, 8, 7, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 9, 6];

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, 81])
 .range(["white", "red"]);
 
var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("width", 40)
 .attr("height", 40)
 .attr("stroke", "gray")
 .attr("x", d=>hccol.indexOf(d.col)*40)
 .attr("y", d=>hcrow.indexOf(d.row)*40)
 .attr("fill", d=>color(d.value));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```